# getting output of sqlcmd query in to batch variable

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

Hi i want to get output of query into batch variable. so i did

```
sqlcmd /U sqladmin /P pwd /d mydb /v nesql= xxx hostsql = yyy -e /I /Q "set nocount on;select count(*) from mytable where host='$(hostsql)' and ( LocaA='$(nesql)' or LocaB='$(nesql)' )" -h -1 >prajyodh.txt
```

I am getting the output but getting the extra first line with proper query.

```
set nocount on;select count(*) from mytable where host='yyy' and ( LocaA='xxx' or LocaB='xxx' )
  11105
```

I want to get the first line ommited so that i can get count to a variable by doing

```
set /p varname=<prajyodh.txt
```

and use it in my batch script further.

I have gone trough sqlcmd-?
but i couldnot find the appropriate option.

please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1.This approach is similar to yours:

```
< prajyodh.txt (
  set /p line1=
  set /p line2=

) 
set line
```

2. FOR /F and without temp file.

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('sqlcmd /U sqladmin /P pwd /d mydb /v nesql= xxx hostsql = yyy -e /I /Q "set nocount on;select count(*^) from mytable where host='$(hostsql^)' and ( LocaA='$(nesql^)' or LocaB='$(nesql^)' ^)" -h -1^) do (
     set "second_line=%%S"
     goto :break
)
:break
```

Comment: thanks the first one worked.
the second one gave me some error..but i will debug it somehow..
thanks once again..